# Setting up Eloquent relationships, do I need to employ other relationship types?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, structure

i'm needing some help with setting up the proper relationships for my project.

The best way I can compare it is by considering a student timetable.

I need a user to be able to have many classes, and tasks within each of those classes. However, these tasks should also be linked to the user directly. I want to be able to call $user->tasks() and get all the tasks, rather than going through each $user->period.... The user has many periods, each period has many tasks, but the tasks should belong to user directly.

Any suggestions? Would i need to employ polymorphic relations in my table structure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you need is the "Has Many Through" relationship.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient short-cut
>   for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For
>   example, a Country model might have many Post models through an
>   intermediate User model. In this example, you could easily gather all
>   blog posts for a given country.

In your case, it can be described as "the `user` **has many** `tasks` **through** `period`".

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Just looked at the Eloquent docs and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks again.